# Memory issue on normal Cocoa Apps? (for example preview.app)

Tags: cocoa, memory-management

I opened preview.app and started scrolling up and down between 2/3 pages continuosly for 5 minutes. I noticed that memory increased of 4 or 5 MB. Potentially I could continue forever for obtaining a memory overflow.

Why scrolling up and down memory increases? (I started with 29 MB of Real Mem). Can we trust activity monitor?

[image]

Comment: Virtual memory is complicated.  It's safe to say that it will take you a while to understand what "36.3 MB" really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa and/or Preview are probably cacheing the image(s) you are scrolling through, which is normal (and designed not to take up all your RAM).

Don't be surprised if your own app does this, but be sure your code is not leaking.